# Money vs. Decimal vs. Float Performance issues (SQL data types for Currency value)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

What data type should be selected in case of Currency value column in SQL server. I have read some where on web **Working on customer implementations, we found some interesting performance numbers concerning the money data type. For example, when Analysis Services was set to the currency data type (from double) to match the SQL Server money data type, there was a 13% improvement in processing speed (rows/sec).**   Is it true??

Comment: The data type should be selected **according to your business requirements**.

Comment: What "it" is true? Basically for any desidred difference in measurement you can create experiment that proves it to be true :)

Comment: why think about requirement?? every one need best performance of his application.

Comment: i want to save currency in database.this is my requirement.

Comment: @urzshah , thanks for fun phrase "why think about requirement?? every one need best performance of his application". But in reality most people care about code working correctly first, and fast enough second. And only than worry about the best performance as it usually cost significantly more than fast enough.

Comment: @Alexei : I am asking about to select datatype for currency values and I think it is better to design data base first and then to code an application.

Comment: I've googled the phrase in your question and [found the article](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/09/25/the-many-benefits-of-money-data-type.aspx). I'm sure it's correct but the point they are making is  to ensure that your SQL relational data source and Analysis Services measure groups have matching data types.

Comment: @urzshah, that comment should be your question than... Consider it when asking more: it is very hard to guess what one wants to ask based on a question. In your case question has emphasis on  "compare performance of several data types" not "what data type should I chose for currency in SQL/C#".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What data type should be selected in case of Currency value column in SQL server.

I'd always go for `decimal` unless there was a strong reason not to. `float` is inappropriate since not all decimal values can be exactly represented, and you'll end up with weird artifacts (e.g. you'll have an amount of `48.15000000000000000135`).

`money` is often inappropriate since it has a fixed precision and scale which may not match your actual requirements. And it applies rounding on each intermediate result as well as the final one, which may not be suitable for complex calculations. With `decimal` calculations, you have more control over when rounding will occur (by converting to a `decimal` with a smaller precision).